# How to use np.savetxt(with formatter) and error occured?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is my code which will give you as a dataframe output. and i need to write all the data of value column in the specified formatter to convert into fixed length output using formatter feature in savtxt method.Please help me to solve this?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    def decode(self, s):
        result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s)
        return self._decode(result)

    def _decode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            try:
                return int(o)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    return float(o)
                except ValueError:
                    return o
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
        elif isinstance(o, list):
            return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
        else:
            return o

with open('ouput_data.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f,cls=Decoder)
#print(data)
list=[]
list=(data['data'])
df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['id','value'])
new_df = df.set_index('id')
new_df1=new_df.reindex(np.arange(1, 14)).fillna(' ')
print(new_df1)


new_df1.shape
#print(new_df1)


# In[67]:


# Specifying a formatter to convert to fixed length output
fmt = '%2s%2s%4s%1s%10s%8s%5s%1s%3s%30s%18s%2s%30s'


# In[68]:


# Remove NaNs
#in_df.fillna(' ',inplace = True)


# In[69]:

#print(in_df)
# Writing Output
filename=((data['data'])[0]['value']+".txt")
np.savetxt(filename,new_df1.values,fmt=fmt, delimiter='')
print("Done")
```

**Getting error messsage like**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\10.212.30.30\Share Folder\sriram\ile_3072\DataFrame_3072.py", line 61, in <module>
    np.savetxt(filename,new_df1.values,fmt=fmt, delimiter='')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1352, in savetxt
    raise error
ValueError: fmt has wrong number of % formats:  %2s%2s%4s%1s%10s%8s%5s%1s%3s%30s%18s%2s%30s
```

new_df1 will look this...i want to write the values with formatter

```
id      value
  1            whats up
  2                what
  3                    
  4                    
  5                  HI
  6                    
  7                    
  8                    
  9                    
 10                    
 11                    
 12                    
 13
```

Comment: The number of `% formats` in `fmt` must match the number of columns in the array you are saving.

Comment: Anybody help me to solve this!!!!

Comment: Tell us something about `new_df1.values`, the array that you are trying to write.

Comment: i don't understand !!! will you please elaborate.tell me what i have to edit in my code

Comment: see the question now i added the new_df1 dataframe output will look like this

Comment: advise me on above to solve this....this was eating my head

Comment: Your dataframe has only 1 column.  Maybe its a pandas Series.  Why don't you use pandas `to_csv` method instead?  It should be easier to use.

Comment: My usecase is to write into text file with 106 bytes only ..i have to distribute this all values with total 106 bytes....

Comment: Do you have any advise above this?